# SFML and accents?

Tags: c++, sfml, diacritics

I need to display accents on SFML, but I've make research and it's because of encoding characters.

I use `std::string`, but I don't know how to pass the good encoding to SFML.

I tried to use hexadecimal character code in the string, but it does not work

```
std::string s = L"éèà";
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), s);
```

Does anyone know how to do it with a simple example?

Answer (score 1):

I found ! it was a police problem, 
i try with arial.ttf and now it works !
Sorry for the post thank you